# How do I join multiple select results into a single table?

Tags: postgresql

I have a query which returns monthly averages from the same table, but for different pressure_level's:

```
SELECT some_id, avg(exposure_value) monthly_avg_1000
FROM mytable
WHERE pressure_level = 1000
AND some_id = 7
GROUP BY some_id, date_trunc('month', measurement_time)
```

I then have the same query, but for a different pressure_level:

```
SELECT some_id, avg(exposure_value) monthly_avg_925
FROM mytable
WHERE pressure_level = 925
AND some_id = 7
GROUP BY some_id, date_trunc('month', measurement_time)
```

Both queries return 12 rows (1 per month) with the ID and the average value for the month:

```
some_id | monthly_avg_1000
--------------------------
1       | 0.000023 
1       | 0.000051 
1       | 0.000009 

some_id | monthly_avg_925
--------------------------
1       | 0.000014 
1       | 0.000007 
1       | 0.000131
```

I would like to combine the  two queries so that the monthly_avg_* columns all appear in the final table:

```
some_id | monthly_avg_1000 | monthly_avg_925
--------------------------
1       | 0.000023         | 0.000014 
1       | 0.000051         | 0.000007 
1       | 0.000009         | 0.000131
```

How can I do this?

Comment: why not just joining two in CTE?.. they have same Ids - right?..

Comment: @VaoTsun I'm not very familiar with postgressql & databases in general - I don't even know what CTE is :) P.S Yes, same ID's.

Comment: that's easiest way to do that - without analyzing the structure and queries. check my answer if it works as supposed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have same id, then you can try join:

```
with a as (
SELECT some_id, avg(exposure_value) monthly_avg_1000,date_trunc('month', measurement_time) d
FROM mytable
WHERE pressure_level = 1000
AND some_id = 7
GROUP BY some_id, date_trunc('month', measurement_time)
)
, b as (
SELECT some_id, avg(exposure_value) monthly_avg_925, date_trunc('month', measurement_time) d
FROM mytable
WHERE pressure_level = 925
AND some_id = 7
GROUP BY some_id, date_trunc('month', measurement_time)
) 
select distinct a.some_id, monthly_avg_1000,monthly_avg_925 
from a
join b on a.some_id = b.some_id and a.d = b.d
```

Comment: I expect to get 12 rows (1 per month), but instead I get 144 (12 * 12) - using your query.

Comment: hm - does distinct help?.. look I need structure anyway :)

Comment: Yes, I supply an ID, so the ID is the same.

Comment: Great, thanks. This works. I can't believe it is so complicated just to append the columns!